# Continuous injections of nice spaces into $\ell^2$

Tags: general-topology, separable-spaces

If X is a separable, first countable Hausdorff space, then does there exist a continuous map from X to $\ell^2$?

Intuitively put, can you always fill in the holes of nice spaces?

Comment: You cannot have an embedding, but you want the map to be injective? "into" is ambiguous. You always have a constant map to $\ell^2$ so you need some condition.

Comment: No, not an embedding, just a continuous injection

Comment: If your conclusion is true, then the continuous functions on the space separate the points. I don't think that this is true of every separable first countable Hausdorff space, but I might be wrong. You should look for Urysohns theorem and the context to see conditions under which this holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the [Double Arrow space](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/double-arrow-space/), $[0,1] \times \{0,1\}$ in the lexicographic order topology. Then $X$ is a non-metrisable, compact, first-countable, separable, Hausdorff (even hereditarily normal, being an ordered topological space) and if a 1-1 continuous function $f: X \to Y$ existed where $Y$ is metrisable, then $f$ would be a homeomorphism (as $Y$ is Hausdorff and so $f$ is closed etc.) and hence metrisable too. So from $X$ there can be no injective map into $\ell^2$.

Comment: Nice counter example, I'm wondering if metrizability essential for a counterexample to be possible?

Comment: @AIM_BLB It's the easiest: a space $X$ has an injection into $\ell^2$ implies it has a coarser metrisable topology (i.e. it's submetrisable, as this is called). It is well-known that every separable metrisable space has an embedding into $\ell^2$.

Comment: Oh yea?  Is it possible to have a link to this paper?  This would help so much

Comment: @AIM_BLB the embedding fact is quite well-known, it’s in Bessaga and Pelczynski’s book, or in van Mill’s book on infinite-dimensional topology. It’s originally due to Banach IIRC. It uses a countable family of separating functions.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much Henno; this makes a big difference for me :)